# How do you find questions that disappear?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, 404-not-found

Every now and then a question just disappears from SO. Perhaps it was moved to another site? Or?

Most recently, I was looking at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383691/how-to-write-dates-to-excel-from-c-using-openxml

Upon refreshing the page I found myself in lost in the 404's.

Is it possible to track down where these questions are taken? Do I need to employ a Code Tracker equivalent to the [Man Tracker](http://science.discovery.com/tv/mantracker/)?

Comment: It was deleted by the questioner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it was deleted.  If you have over 10k rep you can see deleted questions, but other than that it'll just appear as you see it.

If you think it was something that shouldn't have been deleted (unlikely), you can send that URL to a moderator and they would be able to view it, I believe.